# Qtip-like bubbles in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, qtip

I'm looking for something like Qtip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) for my Java Swing application.

Comment: ToolTip in Swing, but comings from predinosauries Java edge, long time without any changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/Swing/JToolTip

Just combine both

Or try this
http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/55.html